# How to make flutter listview show millions of items

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I'm tring to write a log viewer application with flutter.

I've learn that ListView.builder could handle larget number, even infinite number of items.

for example:

```
const mockLines = [
  'this is a short line that will display in one line',
  'this is a long line that will display in multiple lines, let us see how long it will be ?',
];
Widget _buildLogView() {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 1000,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final line = mockLines[index % mockLines.length];
      return Text('$index: $line');
    }
  );
}
```

which works good, text got wrapped when it's too long.

[image]

But scrolling got very slow, and memory got blow when I set itemCount to 1000000.

Tried itemExtent:

```
Widget _buildLogView() {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 1000000,
    itemExtent: 20
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final line = mockLines[index % mockLines.length];
      return Text('$index: $line');
    }
  );
}
```

Problem solved.

However, text won't wrap anymore, it just got truncated.

[image]

It seems that there's no way for me to create a listview can handle millions of lines when keeping the 'wrap' behavior.

Am I miss something, or just a limitation of flutter?

===============

A release build, draging scrollbar to 1/3 with itemCount = 1000000

memory keep crimbing up (would finally eat all)

[image]

same on windows:

[image]

Comment: specifying ``itemExtend`` is like setting height of each list items. Which is why the other wrapped lines / next lines are not visible. If you try to increase the itemExtend, you'll start seeing lines.

Comment: You don't need to specify ``itemExtend`` to handle such a large number of items. Probably you're testing on a low end device? Also, showing millions of records doesn't make sense, at least in real life scenario. Any specific reason?

Comment: @OMiShah I'm writing a log analyze tool, which may open files reach 2GB or so.

without itemExtend， on nuc 11 ( 16GB i5-1135G7 deepin linux），even with release build， memory would cost up to 16GB when I drag the scrollbar.

Comment: By device I mean the phone/emulator's config, that you're testing the app on.

Comment: this code shows one billion long lines (i mean 1000 * 1000 * 1000): `class ListWith1000000000LongLines extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: 1000000000,
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
print(i);
return Text('#$i ${"long " * 32} line\n');
},
);
}
}
`

Comment: why not use pagnation, i mean, your screen to scroll its limited, just load what you need to show, and if you want to handle that data, handle it with partition

Comment: @pskink, exactly and with out a problem.

Comment: @OMiShah of course without a problem

Comment: @OMiShah I'm developing the desktop tool, so the device here is exactly the host(nuc), not emulator.

Comment: @pskink have you try draging the scrollbar, is it smooth? How much memory does it cost ? Are you buildint to run on desktop?

Comment: it costs only those few widgets that are visible + `cacheExtent` additional widgets, so you can show as many lines you want: your only problem is loading the data: you cannot basically load the content of 2GB file into memory at once

Comment: btw copy / paste the code i gave you, run it and watch the logs: you will see that few additional calls to `itemBuilder` are made: its `cacheExtent`

Comment: @pskink I edit the question and add a screenshot to explain what happens to the memory. It's growing when dragging the scrollbar (all data is mocking, without loading a file)

Tired your code, same.

Guess it's a bug on linux, Maybe I should chekc windows.

Comment: what do you see on the logs when you try dragging? do you see any prints from my `itemBuilder`?

Comment: @pskink
on first run, print 0 to 13;
with a slightly drag, print too many lines. force stop by ctrl-c. 
last 31576 to 36600 are seen, the earlier prints been dropped by terminal

Comment: so it seems that by default listview tries to refresh itself on every scrollbar move, if it lags for huge content try to implement your custom dragging